# Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres Base-64 en C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, base64

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo en la vista, en el que transformo una cadena de `string` en base64 con *btoa*:

```
 $("#btn_ejemplo").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myContent = btoa(("#myContent").text());
        var url = '/Factura/DescargarXML?textoXML=' + myContent;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
```

en el controlador recibo de esta forma:

```
 public ActionResult DescargarXML(String textoXML)
    {            
        byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64Decode(textoXML));
        var fileStreamResult = File(arr, "application/octet-stream", "DTE.xml");
        return fileStreamResult;
    }

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64Data)
    {
        var b = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
    }
```

Pero cuando decodifico, se me cae diciendo que tiene error:

```
longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres base-64 en System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data)
```

Esto es lo que tiene el string `textoXML`:

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iSVNPLTg4NTktMSI/Pgo8RW52aW9EVEUgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaWkuY2wvU2lpRHRlIiB4bWxuczp4c2k9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvWE1MU2NoZW1hLWluc3RhbmNlIiB4c2k6c2NoZW1hTG9jYXRpb249Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2lpLmNsL1NpaUR0ZSBFbnZpb0RURV92MTAueHNkIj4KICA8U2V0RFRFIElEPSJJRDc4NDUwNDcwLTBfXzFfXzMzX18xMzcxNzUiPgogICAgPENhcmF0dWxhIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMCI CiAgICAgIDxSdXRFbWlzb3I Nzg0NTA0NzAtMDwvUnV0RW1pc29yPgogICAgICA8UnV0RW52aWE MTQ2ODE1OTYtMDwvUnV0RW52aWE CiAgICAgIDxSdXRSZWNlcHRvcj43NTgyNzUxLTI8L1J1dFJlY2VwdG9yPgogICAgICA8RmNoUmVzb2w MjAxNC0wNy0xODwvRmNoUmVzb2w CiAgICAgIDxOcm9SZXNvbD42NjwvTnJvUmVzb2w CiAgICAgIDxUbXN0RmlybWFFbnY MjAxOC0wMS0yMlQxNTo1NTozNTwvVG1zdEZpcm1hRW52PgogICAgICAKICAgIDxTdWJUb3REVEU PFRwb0RURT4zMzwvVHBvRFRFPjxOcm9EVEU MTwvTnJvRFRFPjwvU3ViVG90RFRFPjwvQ2FyYXR1bGE CiAgICAKICA8RFRFIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMCI CiAgICAgIDxEb2N1bWVudG8gSUQ9IkYxMzcxNzVUMzMiPgogICAgICAgIDxFbmNhYmV6YWRvPgogICAgICAgICAgPElkRG9jPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8VGlwb0RURT4zMzwvVGlwb0RURT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPEZvbGlvPjEzNzE3NTwvRm9saW8 CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxGY2hFbWlzPjIwMTgtMDEtMjI8L0ZjaEVtaXM CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxGbWFQYWdvPjE8L0ZtYVBhZ28 CiAgICAgICAgICA8L0lkRG9jPgogICAgICAgICAgPEVtaXNvcj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFJVVEVtaXNvcj43ODQ1MDQ3MC0wPC9SVVRFbWlzb3I CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSem5Tb2M U09DIENPTUVSQ0lBTCBMIFkgQyBMVERBPC9Sem5Tb2M CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxHaXJvRW1pcz5FU1RBQ0lPTiBERSBTRVJWSUNJTzwvR2lyb0VtaXM CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxBY3RlY28 NTA1MDAwPC9BY3RlY28 CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWN1cnNhbD42MDM1OTwvU3VjdXJzYWw CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxDZGdTSUlTdWN1cj40NzQ1Mzg4PC9DZGdTSUlTdWN1cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPERpck9yaWdlbj5GUkVJUkUgNjgxPC9EaXJPcmlnZW4 CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxDbW5hT3JpZ2VuPjczMDE8L0NtbmFPcmlnZW4 CiAgICAgICAgICA8L0VtaXNvcj4KICAgICAgICAgIDxSVVRNYW5kYW50ZT45OTUyMDAwMC03PC9SVVRNYW5kYW50ZT4KICAgICAgICAgIDxSZWNlcHRvcj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFJVVFJlY2VwPjc1ODI3NTEtMjwvUlVUUmVjZXA CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSem5Tb2NSZWNlcD5IRVJOQU4gRU5SSVFVRSBTT1RPIFBJWkFSUk88L1J6blNvY1JlY2VwPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8R2lyb1JlY2VwPkRJU1RSSUJVSURPUkE8L0dpcm9SZWNlcD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPERpclJlY2VwPk1BTlNPIERFIFZFTEFTQ08gTiAxMTY0PC9EaXJSZWNlcD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPENtbmFSZWNlcD5DVVJJQ088L0NtbmFSZWNlcD4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvUmVjZXB0b3I CiAgICAgICAgICA8VHJhbnNwb3J0ZT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFBhdGVudGU QlQ4NDU1PC9QYXRlbnRlPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8Q2hvZmVyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSVVRDaG9mZXI MTYzMzY5MzAtMzwvUlVUQ2hvZmVyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxOb21icmVDaG9mZXI TkQ8L05vbWJyZUNob2Zlcj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9DaG9mZXI CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxEaXJEZXN0PkFWIEZSRUlSRSA2ODE8L0RpckRlc3Q CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxDbW5hRGVzdD5DVVJJQ088L0NtbmFEZXN0PgogICAgICAgICAgPC9UcmFuc3BvcnRlPgogICAgICAgICAgPFRvdGFsZXM CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxNbnROZXRvPjEyMTg4PC9NbnROZXRvPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8VGFzYUlWQT4xOS4wMDwvVGFzYUlWQT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPElWQT4yMzE2PC9JVkE CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxJVkFUZXJjPjIzMTY8L0lWQVRlcmM CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxJbXB0b1JldGVuPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxUaXBvSW1wPjI4PC9UaXBvSW1wPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxUYXNhSW1wPjE8L1Rhc2FJbXA CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPE1vbnRvSW1wPjIwOTk8L01vbnRvSW1wPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8L0ltcHRvUmV0ZW4 CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxNbnRUb3RhbD4xNjYwMzwvTW50VG90YWw CiAgICAgICAgICA8L1RvdGFsZXM CiAgICAgICAgPC9FbmNhYmV6YWRvPgogICAgICAgIDxEZXRhbGxlPgogICAgICAgICAgPE5yb0xpbkRldD4xPC9Ocm9MaW5EZXQ CiAgICAgICAgICA8Q2RnSXRlbT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFRwb0NvZGlnbz4wMTwvVHBvQ29kaWdvPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8VmxyQ29kaWdvPjE8L1ZsckNvZGlnbz4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvQ2RnSXRlbT4KICAgICAgICAgIDxObWJJdGVtPkRJRVNFTDwvTm1iSXRlbT4KICAgICAgICAgIDxRdHlJdGVtPjI5Ljc1NDAwMDwvUXR5SXRlbT4KICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJjYW50aWRhZD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFN1YlF0eT40MDkuNjI1NjAwPC9TdWJRdHk CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJDb2Q UEJhc2U8L1N1YkNvZD4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvU3ViY2FudGlkYWQ CiAgICAgICAgICA8U3ViY2FudGlkYWQ CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJRdHk NzAuNTI4NDAwPC9TdWJRdHk CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJDb2Q SUVGPC9TdWJDb2Q CiAgICAgICAgICA8L1N1YmNhbnRpZGFkPgogICAgICAgICAgPFN1YmNhbnRpZGFkPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8U3ViUXR5PjU1OC4wMDkwMDA8L1N1YlF0eT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFN1YkNvZD5QVG90YWw8L1N1YkNvZD4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvU3ViY2FudGlkYWQ CiAgICAgICAgICA8U3ViY2FudGlkYWQ CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJRdHk MTY2MDMuMDAwMDAwPC9TdWJRdHk CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxTdWJDb2Q U3ViUFRvdGFsPC9TdWJDb2Q CiAgICAgICAgICA8L1N1YmNhbnRpZGFkPgogICAgICAgICAgPFVubWRJdGVtPkxpdHI8L1VubWRJdGVtPgogICAgICAgICAgPFByY0l0ZW0 NDA5LjYyNTYwMDwvUHJjSXRlbT4KICAgICAgICAgIDxDb2RJbXBBZGljPjI4PC9Db2RJbXBBZGljPgogICAgICAgICAgPE1vbnRvSXRlbT4xMjE4ODwvTW9udG9JdGVtPgogICAgICAgIDwvRGV0YWxsZT4KICAgICAgICA8VEVEIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMCI CiAgICAgICAgICA8REQ CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSRT43ODQ1MDQ3MC0wPC9SRT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPFREPjMzPC9URD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPEY MTM3MTc1PC9GPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8RkU MjAxOC0wMS0yMjwvRkU CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSUj43NTgyNzUxLTI8L1JSPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8UlNSPkhFUk5BTiBFTlJJUVVFIFNPVE8gUElaQVJSTzwvUlNSPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8TU5UPjE2NjAzPC9NTlQ CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxJVDE RElFU0VMPC9JVDE CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxDQUYgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8REE CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8UkU Nzg0NTA0NzAtMDwvUkU CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8UlM U09DIENPTUVSQ0lBTCBMIFkgQyBMSU1JVEFEQTwvUlM CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8VEQ MzM8L1REPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPFJORz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPEQ MTM0NjYyPC9EPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8SD4xMzg2NjE8L0g CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L1JORz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxGQT4yMDE3LTExLTIxPC9GQT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxSU0FQSz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPE0 cndORSsvTWlXRmtYdTc1QXpIKzZ1Q0R2Wk4vbE1iS1dPb0dLYzlkaFBSQW5rYmdtaERUL2ZaQS84OWg2WXlUa1JaWitScStDZ0lVbFkzK0dHem9ndXc9PTwvTT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPEU QXc9PTwvRT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvUlNBUEs CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8SURLPjMwMDwvSURLPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvREE CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPEZSTUEgYWxnb3JpdG1vPSJTSEExd2l0aFJTQSI SDdXdmZWYXUwbTJZKzkvSjArS2R6TXVYRWNKOFFtSjgwNm5BbVJBeC9LQTE5UFVWQ2x4dDJHUTJuNWF3TDVMVzFOQkdYcVBPOFNWVkxtM0VaTlkyVnc9PTwvRlJNQT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9DQUY CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxUU1RFRD4yMDE4LTAxLTIyVDE3OjQ1OjQ4PC9UU1RFRD4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvREQ CiAgICAgICAgICA8RlJNVCBhbGdvcml0bW89IlNIQTF3aXRoUlNBIj5EUmJsaWxGb2xvTEI3MVZ1NkNveU51Tml0cXlLYTN6OEpXVkYzL0JXQklZRzlHOXpHcEpHT3RMcXVvSENteGgwUWFxUXZtaVc3TkVkeXhlcHBwSi8wdz09PC9GUk1UPgogICAgICAgIDwvVEVEPgogICAgICAgIDxUbXN0RmlybWE MjAxOC0wMS0yMlQxNzo0ODo0NjwvVG1zdEZpcm1hPgogICAgICA8L0RvY3VtZW50bz48U2lnbmF0dXJlIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjIj48U2lnbmVkSW5mbz48Q2Fub25pY2FsaXphdGlvbk1ldGhvZCBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSLzIwMDEvUkVDLXhtbC1jMTRuLTIwMDEwMzE1IiAvPjxTaWduYXR1cmVNZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjcnNhLXNoYTEiIC8 PFJlZmVyZW5jZSBVUkk9IiNGMTM3MTc1VDMzIj48VHJhbnNmb3Jtcz48VHJhbnNmb3JtIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvVFIvMjAwMS9SRUMteG1sLWMxNG4tMjAwMTAzMTUiIC8 PC9UcmFuc2Zvcm1zPjxEaWdlc3RNZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjc2hhMSIgLz48RGlnZXN0VmFsdWU ZzJCSHViZ2J6ekJ6WjVqQ3FzYXdPZ1VRbzA0PTwvRGlnZXN0VmFsdWU PC9SZWZlcmVuY2U PC9TaWduZWRJbmZvPjxTaWduYXR1cmVWYWx1ZT4KTTNjWWxHTlp0NXZiNExHN1gyWWxVTldOZ1dsblM1dFR2Q2g2K3NqajBrN0VUdlVvdzJleGFmcUNNbTRPRkowNQp6cGd2V1oyZHhicVh2bXNnTnEzNmlvVXRBV1l4b1BLbEZsK1ZjNVVBVmVYaU1zWWg5bHo4SytFMFBYaDFua3Q5CjZLWmFhcGFBb0F5VjkxUlNkYnN0cnppSXNVaFBxSFNlMjZDek5GdmRpems9CjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlVmFsdWU PEtleUluZm8 PEtleVZhbHVlPjxSU0FLZXlWYWx1ZT48TW9kdWx1cz4Kc1NGMXJ0Tm05Nldsd2VRWHlac01vRUZHUXVsbFR0S2RPbGcyTC9TWEZzdm5wUTI1d0paeUV6R2tTN0w2YmJuVQpOd2ZIbEkwMVJpV2xCNFB3N2ltTGZVcXpQTlFWTTFxMUU3MGl6MzFBek1WUk9VbjZRYldhU0FsN3ZRWUJpT3ZwCk9LN09QV1ZZbUR6ZjRVNCtpUEFpbDVDUlByVG9qMDVGVkhRUUcwd2FZRVU9CjwvTW9kdWx1cz48RXhwb25lbnQ QVFBQjwvRXhwb25lbnQ 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 PC9LZXlJbmZvPjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlPgogICAgPC9EVEU PC9TZXREVEU PFNpZ25hdHVyZSB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnIyI PFNpZ25lZEluZm8 PENhbm9uaWNhbGl6YXRpb25NZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9UUi8yMDAxL1JFQy14bWwtYzE0bi0yMDAxMDMxNSIgLz48U2lnbmF0dXJlTWV0aG9kIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnI3JzYS1zaGExIiAvPjxSZWZlcmVuY2UgVVJJPSIjSUQ3ODQ1MDQ3MC0wX18xX18zM19fMTM3MTc1Ij48VHJhbnNmb3Jtcz48VHJhbnNmb3JtIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvVFIvMjAwMS9SRUMteG1sLWMxNG4tMjAwMTAzMTUiIC8 PC9UcmFuc2Zvcm1zPjxEaWdlc3RNZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjc2hhMSIgLz48RGlnZXN0VmFsdWU VkFpMlE3bnE4ZlFkQ0ZJRmVmdHpqYzduVkIwPTwvRGlnZXN0VmFsdWU PC9SZWZlcmVuY2U PC9TaWduZWRJbmZvPjxTaWduYXR1cmVWYWx1ZT4KVCtRa2lCeTR1bXIvKy9tWit6eGRNdVpheThENVRyMWhwTWQ1ekVkSVFCOWlMd1NaUTFyUlZnbnQ4TjJOSCttbQpXREdtSDVRWXN5Skp0NzNJd25EbzAzdklmZ2JzNnMzcHZ0MWl1bVhFZ3pwTU53RXpEbFk5cUhqQTNKVVZINU90CkE3eG43ckt0Y0JCTmVmVGR4anJ6cDViRG1naXk5RGM0cm52bURuVzN0Slk9CjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlVmFsdWU PEtleUluZm8 PEtleVZhbHVlPjxSU0FLZXlWYWx1ZT48TW9kdWx1cz4KOEJ6MkF2YU9XeEJXblV3WDNCV3B1NVRhWDY3RGp5cmlWM3N5TTZ2Z0ZkN1luTFFyY0I0RnZWUFhFemFvenZicQpTaXNFajhQM3NlNWR0T0NoUUhaRWlYS1NQaWYxejVFUWY3N21QQ2lzR3k1dktYbzNXWUtuNlFSWlFhZUp1R0hHCk5VZ2xvbFFNVDFkbm9RRmQyZXlpaEswN0EvNXpvSTZFRHVrbVZTSjBOd009CjwvTW9kdWx1cz48RXhwb25lbnQ QVFBQjwvRXhwb25lbnQ 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 PC9LZXlJbmZvPjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlPgogIAo8L0VudmlvRFRFPg==
```

Me llama la atención que al final tiene dos signos igual(`==`); le agrego o le saco el igual, pero me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que algunos caracteres del B64 estén teniendo conflicto con los de una URL válida, intenta lo siguiente:

```
byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64Decode(textoXML.Replace(" ", "+")));
```

Comment: shop350 sos un capo re capo, estuve luchando con esto 2 días y tu indicación del blanco y el + era justo mi problema por algún motivo al pasarla a variable de session o no se en que pasamano la clave cambia los + por blancos y ese era mi problema.
le agregue el .replace(" ","+") y solucionado el problmea Realmente me ayudaste un montón, mil gracias.